# Equal interval data classification technique formula confusion

Tags: data-analysis

The formula for breaking a sequence of values into groups of equal ranges is:

max - min / number of categories

I would like to know why is it necessary to subtract the maximum value from the minimum value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That captures all of your data. If it was smaller range it wouldn't, and if it was bigger, who cares about the extra stuff where your data doesn't exist?

Comment: Ah I see, I did suspect as much. Many Thanks!